# How to get postgresql to interpret backslashes as escape characters in a bound value?

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
$json_string = '[{"text":"And I quote, \"Hello world!\""}]';
$query = "INSERT INTO table (json_column) VALUES (:bind)";
$bind = array('bind' => $json_string);
```

The problem is that the JSON string has escaped double quotes.

I understand that the SQL standard is to interpret backslashes as literal characters, and in my postgresql database, standard_conforming_strings is on (as it should be). I understand that if I were using a literal string in the query, I could use the format `E'[{"text":"And I quote \"Hello world!\""}]'` and postgresql would interpret the backslashes as escape characters. But I am binding the values in PHP.

So how can I get postgresql to interpret backslashes as escape characters in the bound value? I tried `E:bind` but received an error "column e$1 does not exist".

Comment: you should consider using pgsql `prepare` functions, which make you possible to give the string you want, and the pgsql library will escape the string, when calling `bindParameter` like method

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.bindparam.php first example

Comment: The application I am working with uses MDB2. I find that the problem apparently lies here as things work using PDO.